# StackOverflowException by using explict interface implementation having covariant generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, covariance

I'm extending the exisiting [`IClonable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface using a covariant generic argument.

```
public interface ICloneable<out T> : ICloneable
{
    new T Clone();
}
```

Now I implemented this interface in a base class.

```
public class Base : ICloneable<Base>
{
    public string StrValue { get; set; }

    Base ICloneable<Base>.Clone()
    {
        var result = (Base)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(this.GetType());
        result.StrValue = this.StrValue;
        return result;
    }

    public virtual object Clone()
    {
        return ((ICloneable<Base>)this).Clone();
    }
}
```

Calling `Clone()` works as expected and returns a new instance of base class having the same values.

I created a derived class of `Base` that implements the interface `ICloneable<T>` again to return this new type:

```
public class Sub : Base, ICloneable<Sub>
{
    public int IntValue { get; set; }

    Sub ICloneable<Sub>.Clone()
    {
        var result = (Sub)base.Clone();
        result.IntValue = this.IntValue;
        return result;
    }

    public override object Clone()
    {
        return ((ICloneable<Sub>)this).Clone();
    }
}
```

But if I call `Clone()` on an instance of `Sub` I run into a StackOverflowException because `object Base.Clone()` calls `Sub ICloneable<Sub>.Clone()` of class `Sub`.

The problem is the covariant generic type parameter. If I remove `out` all works as expected.

The question is why does `((ICloneable<Base>)this).Clone()` point to `Sub.Clone()`?

Is co- and contravariance only syntactic sugar and the compiler searches for the lowest possible type in the derivation hierarchy? That means that `ICloneable<Base>` will be changed to `ICloneable<Sub>` by the compiler.

I didn't find any official justification that explains this behaviour.

Testcode (excluding the interface and `Base` and `Sub`):

```
var b = new Sub { StrValue = "Hello World.", IntValue = 42 };
var b2 = (Base)b.Clone();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is co- and contravariance only syntactic sugar and the compiler searches for the lowest possible type in the derivation hierarchy?

Co/contravariance has nothing to do with syntactical sugar. It allows you to pass "smaller", more specific types (covariance) and larger ones (contravariance) with specific compiler restrictions, at compile time.

Because your `T` parameter is marked as `out`, the CLR will look at run-time for any override implementation of `Clone`.

The compile time binding is a `callvirt` to `base.Clone`, that doesn't change:

```
.method public hidebysig newslot virtual 
instance object Clone () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2089
    // Code size 7 (0x7)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: callvirt instance !0 class ICloneable`1<class Base>::Clone()
    IL_0006: ret

} // end of method Base::Clone
```

Run-time is where the [polymorphism happens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx).

The fact that removing `out` calls the base emphasises that exactly.

Comment: _the CLR will look at run-time for any override implementation of `Clone`_ - maybe I didn't understand you correctly but there is no override implementation of `ICloneable<T>.Clone()`. The only override of `Clone` is the ungeneric one `IClonable.Clone()`. Maybe you mean that the CLR is looking for a more specific type at run-time, find it and changes the call to the more specific type. That's okay. Is there any way to prevent the CLR from doing this in this particular case?

Comment: @Vera rind Because `ICloneable<out T>` is covariant, when you call `((ICloneable<Base>)this).Clone();`, the casting of `this` matches `ICloneable<Sub>`, rather than `ICloneable<Base>`.

Comment: Yes I understand. but the last question is still open: Is there any way to prevent the CLR from doing this in this particular case?

Comment: @Verarind Is there any particular reason your extending the existing `ICloneable` instead of simply implementing your generic one?

Comment: Yes because there's some Code that doesn't know the exact type that also needs to create a clone. We've dynamic UI that reflects over the properties and creates a layout. Do be able to cancel all changes we need a clone and in that case we're using `IClonable`. All other parts that know the type uses `ICloneable<T>`.

Comment: @Verarind And do you actually need covariance when cloning `T`? e.g Will there ever be a situation when calling `base.Clone` should emit to a derived implementations clone?

Comment: Not really. `IClonable<out T>` was created some years ago but I think there is currently no usage of covariance. I added it because it was possible and maybe someone need it in the future. I know that removing it will solve my problem. Our case has been solved without using the cast to the base type. The question was get a deeper look into the handling of co- and contravariance. Your answer helped alot. Tank you. I gather your questions that there is no way to prevent it. - No problem.